# Unity - What to do when PlayerPrefs data cleared when browser history is cleared?

Tags: firebase, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, pubnub, playfab

Currently, I have a lot of data stored using *PlayerPrefs*, such as *total scores*, important *indices*, and more.

How can I best save *PlayerPrefs* data in a WebGL game in the event that data gets cleared when the players clear their browser history?

Comment: You can use [PubNub Objects](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/introducing-objects-v2-store-for-user-and-channel-metadata/) to store these PlayerPrefs. Look at [`setUUIDMetadata`](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/unity/api-reference/objects#set-user-metadata).

Comment: Your client code can `setUUIDMetadata` when things need to be updated, and on the *receiving end* of that update, you can capture the confirmation of those changes using the `UserEventResult` callback of the [`SubscribeCallbackHandler `](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/unity/api-reference/configuration#adding-listeners). Though that last part is optional. It allows you to listen to other player's user updates, too, if that is preferred/required. Hit [PN Support](https://support.pubnub.com) for more if needed!

Comment: For about PubNub Objects *User/UUID Metadata*, see https://www.pubnub.com/docs/connections/users-metadata

Comment: You can use [`SetChannelMetadata`](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/unity/api-reference/objects#set-channel-metadata) for non-user (game scope) state that needs to be persisted.